# React: Writing a function to pass as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, jsx

Basically, I've been tasked with editing a UI as a mini challenge to help get me into programming.

I want to add a date picker to my search bar in order to narrow down the search to between two dates. I have the UI working, although when the user selects a date using the picker, the date on the picker doesn't update. Nothing happens, and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code:

**Search box:**

```
import React from "react";

import { TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

import "./SearchBox.css"
import DatePickerWidget from "./DatePickerWidget"

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { searchTerm: "", results: "" };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.validateSearch = this.validateSearch.bind(this);
    this.clear = this.clear.bind(this);



  
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: this.props.searchTerm });
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.searchTerm !== this.props.searchTerm)
      this.setState({ searchTerm: this.props.searchTerm });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.update({ searchTerm: this.state.searchTerm });
    this.setState({ results: this.state.searchTerm });
  }

  validateSearch() {
    return this.state.searchTerm !== "";
  }

  clear() {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: "", results: "" });
    this.props.update({ searchTerm: "" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form id="search-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Button
            style={{ width: "40%" }}
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary"
            onClick={this.clear}
            disabled={this.state.results === ""}
          >
            Clear
          </Button>
          <TextField
            style={{ flexBasis: "100%" }}
            variant="outlined"
            label="Search Term"
            type="search"
            name="searchTerm"
            value={this.state.searchTerm}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <Button
            style={{ width: "40%" }}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            disabled={!this.validateSearch()}
            type="submit"
          >
            Search
          </Button>

          <DatePickerWidget update={this.props.update}/>

        </form>
        {this.state.results && (
          <Typography align="center" variant="body1">
            Displaying results for: {this.state.results}
          </Typography>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


export default SearchBox;
```

**Date picker widget:**

```
import React from "react";
import "date-fns";

import { Paper } from "@material-ui/core";

import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

class DatePickerWidget extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Paper id="date-picker-widget" elevation={8}>
        <Paper id="date-filters" elevation={8}>
          <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              margin="normal"
              id="date-picker-dialog"
              label="Start Date"
              format="yyyy/MM/dd"
              value={this.props.startDate}
              maxDate={this.props.endDate}
              onChange={(date) => this.props.update({ startDate: date })}
              KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change start date",
              }}
            />
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              margin="normal"
              id="date-picker-dialog"
              label="End Date"
              format="yyyy/MM/dd"
              value={this.props.endDate}
              minDate={this.props.startDate}
              onChange={(date) => this.props.update({ endDate: date })}
              KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change end date",
              }}
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        </Paper>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

export default DatePickerWidget;
```

I know that I need to write a function called update and pass it to the date picker as a prop... i just don't actually know how to do that or what it should look like.

Any help is appreciated as I'm just starting to enter this complicated programming world.

Here is a codesandbox link for easier reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-torvalds-phoxq

Comment: It looks like you can put this on codesandbox, can you do that?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-torvalds-phoxq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DatePickerWidget isn't updating because it doesn't have **a state**, you should add a state in which upon the change to your dates is reflected.

I.e. [DatePickerWidget](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-dan-woctt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is actually in your `index.js` file.  You are importing `DatePickerWidget` instead of `Searchbox`.  Therefore, when you create your `<App />` component you aren't passing an `update` function.  I added an example where you are passing an update function [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-brook-mj82i?file=/src/index.js) and it seems to work.  I tried updating the code to use `Searchbox` instead, but there are other dependencies (CSS, etc.) that would need to be resolved.  Let me know if that helps!

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./DatePickerWidget";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App update={() => console.log("here")} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the update function and pass as below.

```
const update = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
};
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <App update={update} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

[image: example]